# Needle in haystack multiple files

Tags: php

I'm trying to search a needle in multiple haystacks (multiple files) and then show in which files the needle was found.

some code...

```
 $needle = $_POST['needle'];

foreach (glob("files/*.txt") as $file) 
{
        $file_handle = fopen($file, "r");

    while (!feof($file_handle)) 
    {
        $haystack = fgets($file_handle);
    }
    fclose($file_handle);


}

    if(stristr($haystack, $needle) === FALSE) 
    {
        echo  $needle.' not found in string';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'found'; // --> show directories? 
    }
```

Comment: Okay. Do you have a question?

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
$haystack = fgets($file_handle);
```

will mean that `$haystack` will be the last line of the last file.

Is that what you mean?

Not

```
$haystack .= fgets($file_handle);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will do something like this

```
   $needle = $_POST['needle'];
    $is_found = FALSE;

    foreach (glob("files/*.txt") as $file) 
    {
            $file_handle = fopen($file, "r");

        while (!feof($file_handle)) 
        {
            $haystack = fgets($file_handle);
           if(stristr($haystack, $needle)){
              $is_found = TRUE;
              break;
           } 
        }
        fclose($file_handle);


    }

        if(!$is_found) 
        {
            echo  $needle.' not found in string';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'found'; // --> show directories? 
        }
```